# Pandas: count unique users using rolling window

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe with time and user_id

```
              time           user_id
2023-02-20 00:00:20  5008662006351712
2023-02-20 00:01:25  5008662006474892
2023-02-20 00:04:28  5008662006889403
2023-02-20 00:05:33  5008662006351712
2023-02-20 00:07:36  5008662004944382
2023-02-20 00:08:37  5008662006760417
2023-02-20 00:09:38  5008662004941892
2023-02-20 00:11:40  5008662006810617
2023-02-20 00:14:50  5008662006936927
2023-02-20 00:15:52  5008662005514572
2023-02-20 00:16:58  5008662004874462
2023-02-20 00:17:01  5008662006937193
2023-02-20 00:17:05  5008662006914843
2023-02-20 00:18:05  5008662006871041
2023-02-20 00:19:06  5008662006478082
```

I want to count the number of unique users in each window size * "5T".
The problem I encountered is I can `resample` this data to "5T" but I can't use then `rolling` because it works only with numeric data:

```
window_size = 2
df = df.resample("5T", label='right', on='time').apply(lambda x: list(set(x))).reset_index()
df = df.rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=window_size, center=False).nunique()
```

The data after `resample` looks like

```
             time    user_id
2023-02-20 00:05:00 [5008662006351712, 5008662006889403, 500866200...
2023-02-20 00:10:00 [5008662004941892, 5008662006760417, 500866200...
2023-02-20 00:15:00 [5008662006810617, 5008662006936927]
2023-02-20 00:20:00 [5008662006871041, 5008662006937193, 500866200...
```

How should I change my code to get this output?

```
              time  user_id
2023-02-20 00:05:00 NaN
2023-02-20 00:10:00 6
2023-02-20 00:15:00 6
2023-02-20 00:20:00 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["user_id"] = (
    df.reset_index()
    .rolling(window=window_size, min_periods=window_size, center=False)["index"]
    .apply(lambda i: len(set(df.loc[i, "user_id"].sum())))
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                 time  user_id
0 2023-02-20 00:05:00      NaN
1 2023-02-20 00:10:00      6.0
2 2023-02-20 00:15:00      6.0
3 2023-02-20 00:20:00      8.0
```

Comment: It returns an error `TypeError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,) `

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you don't need to do `list(set(_))` operation, if you just want to calculate the rolling count. See code below:

```
df2 = df.resample("5T", label='right').apply(lambda x: len(set(x))).reset_index()
df2['count'] = df2.rolling(2)['user_id'].sum()
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
                 time  user_id  count
0 2023-02-20 00:05:00        3    NaN
1 2023-02-20 00:10:00        4    7.0
2 2023-02-20 00:15:00        2    6.0
3 2023-02-20 00:20:00        6    8.0
```

Comment: It does not work as it counts user twice if user is present in both first and second 5-minute window